# how to setup a mongoDB server to accept remote connection

Tags: mongodb

How to setup a mongoDB server (on centos ) to accept connection from other PC (for developing) , I set bind-ip ,but not work.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: I'd rather suggest http://dba.stackoverflow.com. Meanwhile, you might want to stop the iptables service.